# Combine two audio blob recordings

Tags: html5-audio, audio-recording, recorder.js

I am using [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) to record two audio files on my web page, which then creates recordings as blobs.

Once I have these audio blobs I would then like to combine them both into one track to be played by another html5 audio player.

I've searched the internet but I can't seem to find any documentation on combining two blob files into one.

I've found how to concatenate one blob to the other but I'm wanting to merge the files at the beginning.

i.e. - sound 1 is singing and sound 2 is guitar.

Comment: When you say 'merge', do you want to concatenate the blobs (sound 1 plays, then sound 2 plays), or do you want to mix the blobs (sound 1 and sound 2 play at the same time)?

Comment: @MultimediaMike - I want to mice the blobs, in the browser if possible and then upload to the server

Comment: I've never seen 'mice' used as a verb. Can you expound?

Comment: Sorry typo, merge, take both of the blobs and merge them from the beginning of each track.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to do mixing. Perhaps ask the new web audio API (available in some browsers) to do it? Or do you want (or need) to perform this manually in JavaScript?

Comment: What part of the Web Audio API could i use? I can't seem to find a bit function that i could use

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar attempt using recorder.js and it did not work out for me too. Even after downloading the concatenated audio file, the time duration displayed by the audio player remained as the time duration of the first audio blob, though the whole concatenated audio content was available. So after several changes and hair tearing moments I chose to concatenate using ffmpeg. Here is link to my repository ([Audio-Recording-App](https://github.com/abhijayghildyal/Audio-Recording-App-AngularJS-NodeJS))

Comment: This should be a comment instead, as it does not answer to the question. Also a link even if is useful, it is not enought, as it may get broken soon. Improve your answer or probably it will be deleted

Comment: I can't add comments. I need at the least 50 reputation